# regex with tcl and $ in variable value

Tags: tcl

I need help with this regex for tcl. I want to detect the $ character but it isn't flagging. Any ideas?

```
set cell {ABC_ONE_123_$12345$wc_PIE_IN_SKY}
string match $ $cell
```

Comment: Maybe needs escaping with backslash? `\$`

Comment: % string match \$ $cell
0
doesn't work ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**string match and glob patterns**

`string match` does a match against a *glob pattern*, not a regular expression. Plus, it will try to match the whole string. The glob pattern `$` doesn't match since the string has much more than just a dollar sign. However `*$*` does, since it says "zero or more characters, a dollar sign, and zero or more characters". Because `$` is treated specially by the tcl shell, you must quote it properly.

For example:

```
% string match {*$*} $cell
1
% string match *\$* $cell
1
```

**regular expressions**

If you really want to do a regular expression search rather than a glob pattern match, use the `regexp` command. In this case, you must a) protect the $ from normal tcl interpretation just like with `string match`, and b) because it is special to regular expressions, you must protect the dollar sign from regex interpretation.

Here's an example:

```
% regexp {\$} $cell
1
% regexp \\\$ $cell
1
```

Comment: Tcl only thinks `$` is special when it is followed by an alphanumeric, `_`, `:`, `{` or `(`.

Comment: @DonalFellows: thanks for the reminder. My tcl skills are getting rusty.